# Selenium; Unable to find element by class in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

Trying to test a simple page using Selenium running from Visual studio 2013 in C#. Internet explorer 11 starts and goes to the correct page, but cannot find an element from it's class (the very next thing it does). You can use developer tools to see this class as clear as day and this is the only place it's used. Note this works fine in Chrome and Firefox, using the same test .

The HTML is;

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Log in">
```

and the code I'm using to find it is;

```
IWebElement logIn = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName("btn")));
```

I've tried turning "Protected mode" to off for all four internet zones, but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue with the Native vs Synthetic event of operating system. Read [this](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/06/whats-wrong-with-internet-explorer.html). Disabling native events of IEDriver should help you in such case.

I do the following with same environment you have

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { EnableNativeEvents = false };
Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be fixed if you use CssSelector or Xpath instead of ClassName

```
IWebElement logIn = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("input[class='btn btn-default']"));
```

Comment: This just times out waiting.